# Using jQuery.get with a file up a directory?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to write a simple utility app that's just run locally.  It'll read from a list of files using jQuery.get and then display them along with some meta-data (which resides in a separate file).  The images and meta files live in ../scored_images/*.[jpg|meta]

I can load the file list with jQuery.get just fine (it's in the current directory), and I can load up the images and display them without a problem.  However when I go to load the meta file for display, jQuery.get seems to silently fail.  I can load them fine if the path doesn't have ../ in it.   Is there a way to work around this behavior?

Comment: This is relative to the javascript or relative to the page?

Comment: Dude. We need more information.  This post means nothing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, quoting from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/),

> If a request with jQuery.get() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError() method or. As of jQuery 1.5, the .error() method of the jqXHR object returned by jQuery.get() is also available for error handling.

So when you do the `GET` request, you should tack on:

```
$.get('url').error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  //handle error. this can help you find the problem.
}
```

Other than that, I can't say much more without some code from you. I tried to do what you described (as I understand it) and it worked fine for me. I ran:

```
$.get('../data/test.meta').success(function (data) {
  $('#content').append(data);
});
```

from `index.html` in this directory:

[image: Directory]

Let me know if I'm not understanding something and I'll try to help out more.